# How to List a my Folder in a UWP App

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app

I have a folder, let's say "C:\Downloads\Comic" and I would list all the files in this Directory, but I didn't find a way how.
The only way I found is with the help of a FolderPicker.

```
private async Task PickDirAndListfiles()
{
    var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
    folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    if (folder != null)
    {
        var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
        foreach (var storageFile in files)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(storageFile.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

But I know where the folder is and I don't want to pick it first. I want just this one folder!

How can I simply list my folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create this folder from your app you can use :

```
Windows.Storage.DownloadsFolder
```

and then you'll be able to access it.

If it's an already existing folder you'll need to ask the user to pick the folder/file and use :

```
StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList
```

to get a token that will be used for retrieving the corresponding folder/file without asking the user again and again to pick an item.

Alternatively you can declare capabilities to allow your app picking files without user interaction : [Declaring capabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations)